# MVC 4 skip function with variable shows unwanted error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination, skip

I want to create a pagination in MVC 4 with entity data model. My **Home/NameDetailsPage** works fine which return me all the rows at a time. But I want to show this data with pagination as there are so many rows. So i have tried like this

```
 public ActionResult NameDetailsPage(int page)
    {

        var context = new BlogContext();
        IQueryable<string> list;
        list = from m in context.Blogs.OrderBy(m => m.BlogId)
               select m.Name;

         ViewBag.total=list.ToArray().Length;

        return View("NameDetails", list.Skip(page * 4).Take(4));
    }
```

here page number indicates that  I want to skip page*4 rows to get the next 4 rows. Unfortunately I have found these error.

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult NameDetailsPage(Int32)' in 'webpro.Controllers.HomeController'.
An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

What should I do ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error gives you the answer; `page` is a non-optional parameter. 
In other words the routing engine cannot find a suitable parameter-less action method, or an action method with optional parameters.

You need to set `page` as an optional parameter

```
public ActionResult NameDetailsPage(int page = 1)
{
...
```

Or pass the default value via a route definition.

Comment: I have tried this. It removes errors but   the pagination is not  working.Page variable  always get the default argument.

Comment: @sharif How are you constructing your pagination links? If you are trying to include the page as a parameter in the path (i.e /home/namedetailspage/2/), then you will need to create a route definition to suit. Otherwise passing page through via the query string will automatically be bound to the page parameter (i.e. /home/namedetailspage?page=2).

Comment: Just after your recent  comment I have solved my problem . Thanks a lot.Do me a another simple  favour that is what should I write if i want to use like **/home/namedetailspage/2** as it really pretty fine for **/home/namedetailspage?page=2**. Thanks again.

Comment: @sharif Tried answering in the other question you created regarding the routes. Hopefully it helps

Comment: Thanks @brent . I thought you are gone. one up and accepted your ans :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, making the parameter Nullable satisfies the condition expected.  This is demonstrated at the head of the method NameDetailsPage() below.

Another suggestion about LINQ to Entities, not asked, but provided as well, is to avoid pulling the whole set locally, see the use of .Count() below.

Code organization wise, the reason I put the paging bits at the top is that if there is something amiss, ie that the client requested page -1 (add validation), this is dealt with ahead of hitting the data store.

I also changed the LINQ query itself to use the extension methods exclusively.  This could have been done instead by changing the LINQ query to use integrated query syntax exclusively.  The point is to use one or the other as much as possible.  It is an unnecessary difficulty placed on the maintainer of the code to have to think about both syntaxes.

```
public ActionResult NameDetailsPage(int? page)
{
    // TODO: add validation of parameters
    // TODO: REVIEW page size as a hard-coded constant will likely become a user-input
    const int pageSize = 4;
    var pageNumberRequested = page ?? 1; //<< assuming page is 1-based, a person would say "page 1"
    var skipRecords = (pageNumberRequested - 1) * pageSize;
    var takeRecords = pageSize;

    var context = new BlogContext();
    var blogEntries = context.Blogs.OrderBy(blog => blog.BlogId)
                          .Select(blog => blog.Name);

    var totalCount = blogEntries.Count(); //<< let the server-side use an index rather than shipping all of the records, which is a huge amount of Net I/O, then using a huge amount of RAM to create an array, only to get the number of elements in the array.

    var pageOfBlogEntries = blogEntries.Skip(skipRecords).Take(takeRecords);

    ViewBag.total = totalCount;

    return View("NameDetails", pageOfBlogEntries);
}
```

Comment: I have replaced my function with yours but this removes error but Page variable is not working @paegun

Comment: The page variable always receiving the same value would be from elsewhere, ie in the view there is likely paging controls such as a hyperlink that has javascript bound to the click event.  That code needs to request the Action NameDetailsPage including the value for the page requested.  Alternatively (not AJAXy), there is a form that has the Action NameDetailsPage and there is an input control with the name "page" to match the parameter for the Action.  Either way, the client needs to send page for the Action to handle the request accordingly.